# Get entire XML except root element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<Employees>
  <Product_Name>
    <hello1>product1</hello1>
    <hello2>product2</hello2>
    <hello3>product3</hello3>
    <hello4>product4</hello4>
  </Product_Name>
  <product_Price>
    <hello1>111</hello1>
    <hello2>222</hello2>
    <hello3>333</hello3>
    <hello4>444</hello4>
  </product_Price>
</Employees>
```

is it possible to convert the following XML to the XML shown below using C#. I tried using remove function but it didn't work. I also tried to get the value of root node. Didn't work

```
  <Product_Name>
    <hello1>product1</hello1>
    <hello2>product2</hello2>
    <hello3>product3</hello3>
    <hello4>product4</hello4>
  </Product_Name>
  <product_Price>
    <hello1>111</hello1>
    <hello2>222</hello2>
    <hello3>333</hello3>
    <hello4>444</hello4>
  </product_Price>
```

Comment: Your desired XML isn't well-formed XML.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Save such text into a file? Pass object representing these nodes somewhere? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it as [XmlNodeList](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.aspx&ei=EZShUJzzEqeJiwLfr4GYAw&usg=AFQjCNFfmOyM8-Gehnm6IMxxzcDrxgyinw&sig2=k3AmTpw1H5_z-mAoHu-9RA) to be well-formed. Here's a working example of how to do it:

```
XmlDocument xml= new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(@"<Employees>
                      <Product_Name>
                        <hello1>product1</hello1>
                        <hello2>product2</hello2>
                        <hello3>product3</hello3>
                        <hello4>product4</hello4>
                      </Product_Name>
                      <product_Price>
                        <hello1>111</hello1>
                        <hello2>222</hello2>
                        <hello3>333</hello3>
                        <hello4>444</hello4>
                      </product_Price>
                    </Employees>");
        var nodeList = xml.SelectNodes("Employees");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(node.InnerXml); //this will give you your desired result
        }
```

Comment: Used stringbuilder instead of Console.WriteLine. It worked well. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to fetch the inner xml,you can use the XmlReader's `ReadInnerXml`.The innerXML is fetched as a string(skipping the root node).

```
var xmlReader = XElement.Load("data.xml").CreateReader();
xmlReader.MoveToContent();
string innerXml = xmlReader.ReadInnerXml();
```

Comment: +1 This perfectly worked for me. Just 3 lines of code. But you can do the same in single line too. The only difference in my version is that I needed to pass a string as a parameter instead of an xml file so I used XElement.Parse("xml here") instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to Linq to XML, you should you `XDocument`.
*caveat: I believe your xml is malformed - you should have something like:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Add the first xml tag to the xml.

```
string xml = @"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
               <Employees>
                 <Product_Name>
                    <hello1>product1</hello1>
                    <hello2>product2</hello2>
                    <hello3>product3</hello3>
                    <hello4>product4</hello4>
                 </Product_Name>
                 <product_Price>
                    <hello1>111</hello1>
                    <hello2>222</hello2>
                    <hello3>333</hello3>
                    <hello4>444</hello4>
                 </product_Price>
              </Employees>";

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

// get the elements
var rootElements = xDoc.Root.Elements();
```

Alternatively, you can load the xml from a file:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("xmlFile.xml");
```